# How to convert base64 encoded file to yii\web\UploadedFile in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

In graphql request I am receiving file as base64 and I have to convert it to UploadedFile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You probably shouldn't even need to convert it to the UploadedFile instance. That class is designed to help handling files uploaded through standard forms.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used graphql but this should give you an understanding of how to manipulate the base64 code.

Try this (replace the file type accordingly):

```
//Given this image
$img = 'data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfdfgh435fdgs';
    
//Remove the data that is not the image string
$clean_string = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,',  '', $img);
    
// Decode the string
$img_data = base64_decode($clean_string);
    
// Transform the string into a file
file_put_contents('/folder/image.png', $img_data);
```

Comment: How I can take image that I put with file_put_contents ?
       $uploadedFile = new UploadedFile();
        $file = $uploadedFile->getInstanceByName('/folder/image.png'); 
?

Comment: You have to end with SaveAs. You have all the methods here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile